# Lucene.NET: Field Name containing search keyword

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I need to know the name of field containing searched keyword e.g. if I have document having three fields:

1. Name of book
2. Author of the book
3. Price of the book

And my search criteria is "Michael simpson" which is available in the field-2 "Author of the book". Now I got the search results containing my search keyword but need to know the name of field which holds this information.

Note: I have only one document and have three fields with one index.

Comment: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Return-Lucene-field-name-when-a-query-is-matched-td3437470.html

Comment: Why do you need to know if it's from the author field? For boosting purposes? Have you looked into storing field (or boost) information as payloads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to parse the searcher explanation in order to get the field names. Following is the code snippet for reference:

```
for (int i = 0; i < searcher.MaxDoc(); i++)
{
    string searchExplanation = searcher.Explain(k, i).ToString();
    int strtIdx = searchExplanation.IndexOf("field=");
    string[] fieldName;
    if (strtIdx != -1)
    {
        fieldName = searchExplanation.Substring(strtIdx).Split(',');
        for (int j = 0; j < fieldName.GetLength(0) - 1; j++)
        {
            if (fieldNames.IndexOf(fieldName[j].Substring(6)) == -1)
            {
                 fieldNames.Add(fieldName[j].Substring(6));
            }
        }
    }
}
```